# Why refreshable bean is not initialized when bean's method is called?

Tags: micronaut

Using Micronaut I have a refreshable bean which I also want to be eagerly initialized. I don't think it is possible to combine `@Refreshable` and `@Context` annotations, so I have to perform eager initialization manually. But it doesn't work the way I expect it to. I have the following classes:

```
@Refreshable
public class MyRefreshableBean {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyRefreshableBean.class);

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        LOG.info("postConstruct");
    }

    public void tryToForceInitialization() {
        LOG.info("tryToForceInitialization");
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Application {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);
    private static ApplicationContext ac;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ac = Micronaut.run(Application.class);
        ac.getBean(MyRefreshableBean.class).tryToForceInitialization();
    }

    @Scheduled(initialDelay = "5s")
    public void delayed() throws InterruptedException {
        LOG.info("delayed");
        ac.publishEvent(new RefreshEvent());
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        ac.getBean(MyRefreshableBean.class).tryToForceInitialization();
    }
}
```

It seems `postConstruct()` is not called after context refresh if a) bean was already initialized in `main()` and b) there is no delay after sending the refresh event. Having `Thread.sleep()` in the code feels like a hack. Is there something else wrong with my code or in my understanding?

Comment: "I don't think it is possible to combine Refreshable and Context annotations" - It is.

Comment: "Why refreshable bean is not initialized when bean's method is called?" - Are you asking why your `postConstruct()` method isn't called?

Comment: Yes, I expect `postContruct()` to be called when a bean is initialized. And it's not called anymore after adding `@Refreshable` in addition to `@Context`.

Comment: I think `postConstruct()` is only invoked after the constructor is invoked, not after beans are refreshed.